# Can I use the Python Interpreter to list a modules' classes and methods, as well as descriptions?

Tags: python-3, gpiozero

I believe there is documentation available online, but for the sake of learning a little more about the interpreter, I am specifically wondering if I can use it to find out what is all available for the button class of the gpiozero module. I have tried things like, `help(module)` and `dir(module)`, but I am not getting any descriptions of what is actually in the module. I am just starting out with all of this stuff so I hope that I have at least some brevity in my description (I apologise if I don't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Pi specific question, but all the normal python commands work (at least as well as in any python shell) e.g.

```
import gpiozero
help(gpiozero)
dir(gpiozero)
```

To document the Button class `help(gpiozero.Button)`

The `gpiozero` Documentation is more helpful. https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: If you like, you can also enter interactive help mode by typing `help()`. Everything that you type therein shall be interpreted as if you enclosed it with `help("")`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dir` and `help` on the whole module or on specific classes or objects:

```
>>> from gpiozero import *
>>> dir(gpiozero)
>>> help(gpiozero)
```

```
>>> btn = Button(2)
>>> dir(btn) # or dir(Button)
>>> help(btn) # or help(Button)
```

Alternatively use the [IPython](https://pypi.org/project/ipython/) shell and you can use e.g. `Button?` + `<Enter>` and get the help quicker.